# Multiple clicks on same ViewPagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-adapter

I am using a ViewPager and have a custom Adapter. I have 3 layouts to create a small widget at the bottom of my home screen. I am able to add widgets inside them and have the whole viewpager clickable but only able to get 1 click event for the whole widget.

Is it possible to have 2 textviews on same layout within the viewpager that can be clicked and send the user to different Activities/Fragments?

I have set each textview to clickable and the viewpager itself but still only getting 1 trigger event no matter which textview I click within the viewpager.

Comment: Why do you need the whole `ViewPager` "clickable"? It seems better to just add `OnClickListener`s to each `TextView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to have 2 textviews on same layout within the viewpager that can be clicked and send the user to different Activities/Fragments?

Yes. You can create a `Fragment` for the layout which can hold whatever views you want. Then add an `OnClickListener` to each `TextView` and perform whatever action you wish. Consider using `Button`s instead of `TextView`s. Users will expect to be able to click on a `Button` but clicking on a `TextView` isn't as common.

Comment: Well its actually a imageview, then a textview seperated by a line then another imageview and a textview. I just need each one clickable and able to send the user to different fragments. I will try using fragments to have each child layout clickable. Thanks

Comment: @AdamGardner Note that you should make individual **views** clickable, not an entire **layout**.